Got roped into (what I’m pretty sure is) a scam conference. What now?
I got roped into what might be a scam conference, called the “International Conference of the Humanities” (name slightly changed for anonymity’s sake) On the website they’ve published the previous year’s presenters and paper titles and lots of photos. Promising, but it all feels slightly off. The fee is $400 and the university I’m doing my PhD in has subsidized my fees, flight, and accommodation. I’ve already paid for everything.
Since it’s a famous city and during the summer, I don’t mind as I’ll take advantage and have a short vacation there with my savings. But I’m willing to cancel going to the conference and fight for a refund. I’m afraid of my work being plagiarized if I do publish it in the proceedings of the conference, as they’ve promised to do. (The concern with plagiarism comes from my underlying assumption that a scummy conference is more likely to act unethically.) Should I go and just not publish in the proceedings? I want to cancel going but I’m afraid the university won't reimburse me then for the trip.

In my field a fee of $400 is for sure not unheard of, and of course I can't know how broad "literally everything" actually is. If it's just one field, say chemistry, it doesn't necessarily indicate a scam. How sure are you that this is actually a scam, and on what basis?

I don't know for sure, but I believe many of these may actually be at best "half scams" in the sense that somebody makes a lot of money not doing that much for it, however the actual conference may happen (i.e., organisers have at least organised something) including serious and proper scientific exchange among those who come, if probably not at a really high level.

@ChristianHennig Hi! Thank you for your follow-up question / comments. I’ll try to address them all.
It might certainly be the case of it being more a scummy conference than scam. I’ll write some details below, while keeping myself anonymous. (I’ve seen scummy conference organizers reply angrily to some forum complaints about them!)
-the conference is titled “International Conference of the Humanities” -there are several conferences being organized by the same company under slightly different names, and all in big, important cities -the website has no information on who’s presenting

If you go, afterwards please write about it here. I'm curious. Personally I wouldn't worry about plagiarism that much by the way (this is a much worse way to make much money with little effort than charging a too high fee). But then I'm not speaking from experience.

Can you find publications from previous conferences of them on the web, or even cited? You may well be right, but in that situation researching previous conferences by the same organisers may give you more information.

@ChristianHennig Hahah bet, I’ll update the thread with all the  details if I end up deciding to go.   But yeah, there are definitely easier, less elaborate ways of scamming people than this! (Or are there??) Anyways, just prayinggg they don’t take my research and run with it. I’m not sure how common it is but I’m still anxious about it.

@ChristianHennig Sorry, missed your previous comment! On the website they’ve published previous year’s presenters and paper titles. Also lots of photos. Promising, but it all feels slightly off

OK but you could look for traces of their publications, also elsewhere.

If it is a scam, then the conference may not actually exist - you might show up and find bewildered / annoyed hotel staff.

Where is your advisor during all these? Did you not ask him/her about the conference first?

@DanielHatton I think the concern is that the work will enter an ecosystem of academic dishonesty and become more likely to be plagiarized - that someone running or attending a scam conference would have no qualms about stealing work that was submitted to it. I agree the risk is limited, though, as most of the eyes on the work will be from the other conference attendees, who are probably as innocent as the OP.

Here's an account of what may be waiting for you: https://www.technologynetworks.com/tn/articles/inside-a-fake-conference-a-journey-into-predatory-science-321619 (in short, probably a "real" conference, but an incredibly messy and uninstructive one)

The link also discusses the real concerns of having engaged with a spam conference: not so much plagiarism (the figures behind that model don't care to publish papers themselves), but you'll drown in spam invites for the foreseeable future since you have proven a soft target (sorry).

You can be plagiarized even if you never attend a scam conference
The two concepts (plagiarism & scam conferences) are unrelated. This is because plagiarism is taking someone else's work and presenting it as your own, and once you make your work public - which is a necessary part of academia - then someone can plagiarize you.
If you're very concerned, be sure to timestamp your work, e.g. by uploading it to some preprint server (because the scam conference's website might not be around for very long, its timestamp might not be available should you need it).

Do you have a supervisor?
Have you discussed this with them or someone else at the university?
Surely in the long run it's better to err on the side of being totally honest with them and explaining your concerns and the situation. Even if you are going to go ahead with your travel to said city if you are sure the conference is a scam, then surely it's better to inform the university given that they (presumably your supervisor?) are paying.
I know you didn't list the above as your biggest concern, but also in view of what you say is your biggest concern (the risk of being plagiarized), I think you'd be better of taking the university in the loop. Were you sole author on the work you submitted? If not, other people's reputation is on the line as well, so you'd want to inform them as well.
If I were you I would seek some senior advise before you do anything else.

Thanks for your response!
All totally valid concerns. I’m the sole author, and it’s my university department + graduate school of arts and sciences that are paying—not advisor/supervisor.
I had to send my advisor / uni department all of the materials the conference has sent me—the advisor approved of it all, and didn’t raise any red flags with me.
I totally agree about erring on the overly communicative side. I’ll ask her directly what she thinks of the conference, see what she says, and work from there.
Thanks again, I hope it all works out somehow…

These conferences usually do take place. The work presented there might not be of great quality, and the sessions may be too broad, so you will not get such a relevant audience, but they usually do the conferencing they promise. They usually are not real scams, but rather low-quality and low-prestige money mills. I would not worry too much about presenting there and having a short paper in the proceedings. It may not bring you too many achievement points, it should not do a real harm either, especially at an early stage of the scientific career.
The risk of being plagiarized appears whenever you publish something. I do not think publishing at a low-tier conference raises the risk too much. You certainly should save your best results for good journal papers, if journal papers are the expected way of publishing in your subject. Still, you can show intermediate results or less important results at various conferences — sometimes more prestigious, sometimes less so.
If you think the conference is a complete scam and nothing happens, then that would be a fraud. The university's legal division would have to decide how to act, given that the university paid for the expenses and should get your conference for their money from the organizing company.

I know some people asked me to update the post once I went.
It was in the conference room lobby of a very fancy hotel. I signed in, and they gave me a name badge and I went inside…it was pretty much empty by the time the conference started. A woman (the organizer?) took pictures the WHOLE time of the five people who were. From her angles, it seemed she was trying to make it seem the room was packed for the pictures they sent later. Some people came, presented, and left as soon as they did.
The actual presenters had NOTHING to do with my field. Absolutely no questions were asked. The organizer didn’t care either, she was eager to move on to the next person and the conference SPED through. There was no end-of-conference discussion nor summary by the organizers. Just a goodbye and all were ushered to the lobby cafe. They did provide food, but none of it was halal nor kosher despite the demographic of most of the attendees. They gave us a participation certificate, lol. It felt super, well, superficial.
They also said we’d be published in several journals, but that was pretty much a lie. We were "published"...on their website.
TLDR
All in all, the conference sucked, but it WAS legit, at least.

That sounds very much like a predatory meeting - see eg. this Nature feature.
https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-024-02358-w
Happens to the best of us.
FWIW, I would not bother about publishing in their proceedings if you've got other options (depends on your field, of course). The 5 people in attendance will presumably not scoop you, and why waste your nice work on a platform with negligible impact and give them legitimacy?

I plan on submitting work for a prize and have the same concerns, but first, regarding the conference, go and as you said have fun whether you enjoy the conference or not, you will enjoy the trip.  And look at it this way, you are publishing a paper and going so technically it is an actual academic conference if you go.  Maybe only one other person goes and you become great friends, you can never predict the future.
Now to protect your copyright, copyright in the sense of simply proving that you are the original author, the only real way to do this is to publish the paper ahead of time.  I started a short list of places that you can submit your paper to for free and that have open access, meaning you can add it without a review process, etc.
As the first link below says on their site - "Scholars can post their early research, collaborate on theories and discoveries, and get credit for their ideas before peer-reviewed publication."
These are all of the links I have saved for open access journals and sites so far, there are many more out there but these seemed to be the more established sites from what I found in my brief search (Google Scholar also lets you track citations to your work):
SSRN Preprint Services: https://www.elsevier.com/products/ssrn-preprint-services
ARXIV Scholarly Papers: https://arxiv.org
Google Scholar: https://scholar.google.com
Springer Open Access: https://www.springernature.com/gp/open-research/about/the-fundamentals-of-open-access-and-open-research
Springer: https://link.springer.com
List of Open Access Publications: https://www.sciencedirect.com/browse/journals-and-books?accessType=openAccess
ScienceDirect: https://www.sciencedirect.com
Have a good time!

I wouldn't worry about it too much. There are many low quality conferences laying around. As long as you have an audience to present and a proceedings to have your paper in you are mostly fine. Just don't expect people to point at you and say you have attended that conference.
Just make sure you have all your documentation in case you show up and there is no conference. But the chance of that happening is very slim.
Also, whenever there is something off, first think of incompetence, not dishonesty. I lost count on how many times I forgot to open a place for students to upload their home works and I had to change the deadline due to that. This happens more if your conference indeed in humanities.
Here is an example: the conference I will soon be joining is a more prestigious one than most, but there were so many red flags in their site. This could have thrown me off if I didn't already know the conference. I am certain someone was too busy to update it on time or properly.
